# IE7 Extra Spacing/Padding between DIV's

Tags: css, layout, html, internet-explorer-7, spacing

Been browsing the questions and Googling it but I can't seem to find a fix for this issue.  The layout looks perfectly fine for the Grid anywhere else except for IE7 (surprise).

http://lalive-branch.aeg-webdev.com/

The boxes should all be within 5 pixels of each other, but in IE7 the spacing below divs get botched up completely.  There are a few fixes I put to try to minimize the display differences between browsers, but this one just boggles my mind completely.

Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated.  Please ignore the jquery error and the likes :), thank you.

Comment: Is there link around those boxes? sometimes links create this little bottom padding and i believe that floating the links solves it.. If its the links fault.

Comment: Hey Lollero, nope--no links around the boxes.  It seems to have been caused by the clear:both; on the gridRow.  Why that happened...I don't know.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove: `clear:both` inside your css code for:

```
.gridRow {display:block; /* Remove - clear:both; */}
```

Then it will work on all browsers.

Comment: Thanks Ahsan, what properties does the clear have that causes this so I can better understand it for future use?

Comment: 'clear:both' actually does; "No floating elements allowed on either the left or the right side".

Answer (score 0):

you have to use script for solve this error of css.

in your core you have to create one javascript and this script you have to create one method like as below.

if(browser_version == 7 || browser_version == 8){
     document.getElementById("your_div").style.padding = padding as you want.
}
else{
      document.getElementById("your_div").style.padding = default padding.
}

i think this can help you for Browser CSS Error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make few changes inside your CSS:

1) Inside .gridRow remove **clear: both** then you should consider adding **overflow** attribute and put all margins and paddings inside .gridRow insted of .gridBox. It's better practise because you need to change only one class when your layout get changed.

```
.gridRow {
    /*clear: both;*/
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much r.pie!  This kills all of the margin and flushes it to the gridRow above, but it's easier to put 1 single conditional css to fix it.  Still looking for a fix-fix though.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want IE7 styles only, you can add the following to your  tag:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
.myIE7onlyClass {/*styles here*/}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thank you Marc, I generally avoid conditional css but because this issue has baffled me, I might just do it.

Comment: Yeah I normally try to avoid it to, but sometimes older IE browser won't play along :) Cheerz